# Opening a position after exceeding the price level - without closing the candle

Tags: pine-script

I would like to open a position immediately after exceeding the price level, and not only after the candle closes. In the screenshot - in place of the green arrow, not the red one. I try strategy (title = "Calculate on every tick example", overlay = true, calc_on_every_tick = true) but it doesn't work. Can someone help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQtqP.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use limit orders for that.

```
//@version=5
strategy("My script", overlay=true)

sma = ta.sma(close, 50)
plot(sma)
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, stop=sma)

if (close < sma)
    strategy.close("Long")
```

[image]